# Exercício da Árvore Utópica, Árvore da Vida etc. etc

Tags: javascript, if, undefined

Bom dia! Estou fazendo o curso do Santander, e o último desafio é o famoso cálculo da altura da árvore da vida. Estou com um problema bem específico. Antes, segue o enunciado:

> As árvores utópicas  crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos:
>
> cada primavera dobram seu tamanho cada verão crescem um metro Se Laura
>   planta uma árvore utópica com um metro, no final do outono, qual seria
>   sua altura depois de N ciclos?
>
> Alguns exemplos:
>
> si N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada);
>
> si N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera)
>
> si N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro mais no verão)
>
> si N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera
>   seguinte)
>
> E assim ... Escreva a função alturaArvoreUtopica, que utilize uma
>   quantidade de ciclos de crescimento, e retorne a altura resultante da
>   árvore de Laura.

Então, como a plataforma é meio ruim, eu costumo fazer o código no CodePen, testar e depois passar para a plataforma no curso. Meu código ficou assim:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica (ciclos) {
  var altura = 1;
  if (ciclos == 0) {
    altura = 1;
  } else {
  for (var i=1; i<=ciclos; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      altura += 1;
    } else {
      altura = altura*2;
    }
    }
    return altura  
  }}
```

No CodePen o código funcionou bem em todos os testes, porém, ao rodar o código na plataforma surgiu o seguinte erro: **Expected undefined to equal 1**.

Alguém sabe o que pode ter ocorrido? Será que foi algum detalhe que deixei passar ou eu devo refazer o código de forma diferente?

Comment: Sua pergunta é sobre  uma ferramenta de testes de terceiros. Nem é sobre uma ferramenta de testes padronizada. A pergunta o uso dessa ferramenta de testes deveria ser feita pra quem fez a ferramenta ou para quem está a usando como método didático.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc esqueceu o return pro caso 0. Altere pra:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica (ciclos) {
  var altura = 1;
  if (ciclos == 0) {
    altura = 1;
    return altura; // aqui
  } else {
    for (var i=1; i<=ciclos; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        altura += 1;
      } else {
        altura = altura*2;
      }
    }
    return altura;
  }
}

console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(0))
```

Pelo que vc falou e pela mensagem, seu código passou provavelmente por um ciclo de testes com valores diferentes. Quando vc chama a função original com o valor 0 o retorno está vindo undefined. Deve ser só isso.
Repare que o último return está dentro do else.

Se fizer a função assim fica mais fácil de ler e entender:

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica (ciclos) {
  var altura = 1;
  if (ciclos == 0) 
    altura = 1;
  else
    for (var i=1; i<=ciclos; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        altura += 1;
      else
        altura = altura*2;
    }
  return altura;
}
```

E essa é pra vc estudar um pouco:

```
let alturaArvoreUtopica2 = (ciclos) => {
  let altura = 1;
  if (!ciclos) 
    return 1;

  [...Array(++ciclos).keys()]
    .slice(1)
    .forEach((_, i)=>(i + 1)%2 ? altura *= 2 : altura++);
  return altura;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Realmente foi uma falta de atenção minha. Muito obrigado também pela dica na organização do código, como estou começando acabo não me atentando a isso e agora percebo como o meu código estava bem bagunçado hahaha

Comment: Que bom que deu certo... editei a resposta com um forma mais avançada pra incentivar a vc progredir um pouco em js :)

Comment: Muitas vezes a identação de código faz com que vc entenda errado o código. Por exemplo, na sua função original dá a entender que o último return está antes da saída da função quando está dentro do else. Uma coisa que ajuda bastante é usar uma IDE que tenha um formatador automático de código.  :)